# Close mobile navigation menu after anchor link click - React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and am trying to create a mobile menu that I somehow created using several online resources. Now the problem is that my mobile menu is not closing after clicking on the Anchor links.

I have three different files (Burger, Navbar, and RightNav). Burger is just for icon transformation, Navbar is for main navigation, and RightNav is the mobile menu.

Can someone please specify how I can close the RightNav after clicking on any menu anchor link?

**Burger.jsx file**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import RightNav from './RightNav';

const StyledBurger = styled.div`
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  align-items:center;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
  display: none;
  top: 5%;

  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    align-items:flex-start;
  }

  div {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
    background-color: ${({ open }) => open ? '#00a993' : '#00a993'};
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: 1px;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;

    &:nth-child(1) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'rotate(45deg)' : 'rotate(0)' };
    }

    &:nth-child(2) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(100%)' : 'translateX(0)'};
      opacity: ${({ open }) => open ? 0 : 1};
       
    }

    &:nth-child(3) {
      transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'rotate(-45deg)' : 'rotate(0)'};
      width: ${({ open }) => open ? '20px':'16px'};
       
    }
  }
`;

const Burger = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  
  return (
    <>
      <StyledBurger open={open} onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} id="burger" className='burger'>
        <div />
        <div />
        <div  />
      </StyledBurger>
      <RightNav open={open}/>
    </>
  )
}

export default Burger
```

**RightNav.jsx file**

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { NavHashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';


const Ul = styled.ul`
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;

  li {
    padding: 18px 10px;
  }

  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    z-index: 1;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    background-color: #13161B;
    position: fixed;
    transform: ${({ open }) => open ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)'};

    top: 10%;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 7rem;

    
  }

`;



const RightNav = ({ open, setOpen }) => {


  return (
    
    <Ul open={open} className="mobile-menu" id="mobile-menu">
     
      <NavHashLink smooth to="/#welcome-section" activeClassName="selected" style={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            What
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink smooth to="/#how-section" activeClassName="selected" style={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            How
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink smooth to="/#IsItAThing-section" activeClassName="selected" style={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Why
        </NavHashLink>
        
        <NavHashLink smooth to="/#team-section" activeClassName="selected" style={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Who
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink smooth to="/#contact-section" activeClassName="selected" style={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Where
        </NavHashLink>
     
        <a href='https://stories.therelevancehouse.com/' style={{ color: '#00a993' }}> 
            Stories 
        </a>
    </Ul>
  )
}

export default RightNav
```

**Navbar.jsx file**

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Burger from './Burger';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import logo from '../images/logomain.png'
import ln from '../images/LinkedIN_white.svg'
import medium from '../images/Medium_white.svg'
import twitter from '../images/Twitter_white.svg'
import fb from '../images/Facebook_white.svg'
import instagram from '../images/Instagram_white.svg'
import '../fonts/norwester.ttf'
import linkedinhover from '../images/LinkedinIconHover.svg'
import facebookhover from '../images/FacebookIconHover.svg'
import twitterhover from '../images/TwitterIconHover.svg'
import instagramhover from '../images/InstagramIconHover.svg'
import mediumhover from '../images/MediumIconHover.svg'
import { NavHashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link'

const Nav = styled.nav`
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  .logo {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }


`
const Navbar = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
    const [lastScrollY, setLastScrollY] = useState(0);
        useEffect(() => {
            const controlNavbar = () => {
                if (typeof window !== 'undefined') { 
                  if ((window.scrollY > lastScrollY) && (window.scrollY > 200) && (window.innerWidth > 1000)) 
                  { 
                    // document.getElementById("navbar").style.padding = "30px 10px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext1").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext2").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext3").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext4").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext5").style.fontSize = "12px";
                    document.getElementById("nav-bar-logo1").style.height = "80px";
                    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "90px";
                    // setShow(false); 
                  } else { 
                    setShow(true);  
                    document.getElementById("navtext").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext1").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext2").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext3").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext4").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("navtext5").style.fontSize = "14px";
                    document.getElementById("nav-bar-logo1").style.height = "105px";
                    document.getElementById("nav").style.height = "120px";
                  }
                  setLastScrollY(window.scrollY); 
                }
              };
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
  
       
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', controlNavbar);
        };
      }
    }, [lastScrollY]);
    
    return (
      <Nav >
   
  

   <nav id='nav'  className={ `${show && 'nav'}`} >
      <a href="./" >
         <img id='nav-bar-logo1' className='nav-bar-logo' alt="Marketing, Branding and Communications Agency"  
          src={logo}  />
     </a>
     <div id='navigation-social'>
       <a href='/'> 
     
       <img className='social-nav' src={ln} alt='linkedin' onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = linkedinhover}  onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = ln} />
      
       </a>
       <a href='/'> 
      
       <img className='social-nav' src={medium} alt='medium' onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = mediumhover}  onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = medium} />
       </a>
       <a href='/'> 
      
       <img className='social-nav' src={twitter} alt='twitter' onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = twitterhover}  onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = twitter} />
       </a>
       <a href='/'> 
       
       <img className='social-nav' src={fb} alt='facebook' onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = facebookhover}  onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = fb} />
       </a>
       <a href='/'> 
       
       <img className='social-nav' src={instagram} alt='instagram' onMouseOver={e => e.currentTarget.src = instagramhover}  onMouseOut={e => e.currentTarget.src = instagram} />
       </a>      
       </div>
       
       <div id='navigation-items'>

       <NavHashLink id="navtext" smooth to="/#welcome-section" activeClassName="selected" activeStyle={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            What
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink id="navtext1" smooth to="/#how-section" activeClassName="selected" activeStyle={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            How
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink id="navtext2" smooth to="/#IsItAThing-section" activeClassName="selected" activeStyle={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Why
        </NavHashLink>
        
        <NavHashLink id="navtext3" smooth to="/#team-section" activeClassName="selected" activeStyle={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Who
        </NavHashLink>

        <NavHashLink id="navtext4" smooth to="/#contact-section" activeClassName="selected" activeStyle={{ color: '#00a993' }}>
            Where
        </NavHashLink>
     
        <a id="navtext5" href='https://stories.therelevancehouse.com/'> 
            Stories 
        </a>
      
       </div>
  </nav>
  <Burger />
  </Nav>
    
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: I have solved this problem by merging RightNav.jsx with Burger.jsx and then used onClick={()=> setOpen(false)} in "Ul". The only disadvantage is this will close the menu if you click anywhere in the Nav. But it's a way around.